# May I send argument to the process.send callback?

Tags: node.js

I'm playing with node.js and I have a doubt about the `process.send` method from the node.js process module. 
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_send_message_sendhandle_callback (This is the
current node.js version I'm playing with)

In the node.js documentation I saw there is a callback argument in the `process.send` method.
I understand the callback is called after send the message, but I don't see anything about the
callback function arguments. My doubt is: Can I send arguments to the callback function via 
message handler?

Suppose I have a cluster and I would like to send a message from a worker to the master and
get a value back. May I set a arguments to the `process.send` callback argument function 
from the message handler in the master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). Here is an example of its usage :

```
var myCallback = function() {
    console.log(this.myCustomArgument);
};


//sending arugment
process.send(message, sendhandle, myCallback.bind({myCustomArgument:'hello from the other side'}));
```